# Does await try to capture context when the current syncContext is already threadPool context?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Example:

```
public async Task Method1()
{
        //uses ASPNetSynchronisationContext 

        await Method2().ConfigureAwait(false);

        //uses ThreadPoolContext as we didn't capture the context above
        await Method3();

       //uses ThreadPoolContext
        await Method4();
}
```

My question is, does "await Method3()" tries to capture context or not? Method4 uses ThreadPool context anyway.

Comment: What do you intend by **syncContext** and **threadPool context**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whether `Method2` returns a complete or incomplete task.

As I describe in my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), `await` will *first* examine its argument to determine whether it has already completed, and if it has, then it will continue executing *synchronously*. If it has *not* completed, then `await` will act asynchronously, which includes (for `Task`s) capturing the context.

So, if the task returned by `Method2` is not yet complete by the time the `await` checks it, then that `await` acts asynchronously, resumes in the thread pool context; `Method3` and `Method4` start in the thread pool context, and their `await`s resume in the thread pool context.

But, if the task returned by `Method2` is completed by the time the `await` checks it, then that `await` acts synchronously, stays in the ASP.NET context; `Method3` and `Method4` start in the ASP.NET context, and their `await`s resume in the ASP.NET context.

It is for this reason that I recommend [once one `await` uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` in a method, that *all* later `await`s in that method also use `ConfigureAwait(false)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).